# How to get push notification history from parse.com? (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, history

How to get all push notification history that I received from parse.com? 
Is there any way to get all history? I can't find any API. Please show me how to get it

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve for the user?

Comment: show the history like Facebook Notification.

Comment: So create a history in your database

Comment: I know. but, I can't get history datas without my server.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible - [Parse question link](https://www.parse.com/questions/can-i-getdelete-push-notifications-history-via-rest-api). Only way to see Push history is through the Dashboard.

Comment: Any update on this from parse side? Means, have they provided any API for this information? I couldn't find any update from Parse.

Comment: Parse as a service is shutting down - http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on. I suggest you move on to a different push provider service (I am using Firebase)